# Generating a heightMap without an Image

Tags: java, maps, terrain, game-development, heightmap

I want to make a world generator so that every time I load it, it generates a new heightmap. To do this I'm using a 2D integer array. The dimensions are the x, z, and the height (y).

Is there some simple generation algorithm that will randomize the terrain?

Comment: [perlin noise](http://www.google.com/search?q=perlin+noise)

Comment: this looks like what im looking for though i have no idea how i would implement it. i already have a loop that goes through all the different coordinates but i dont know what to do from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) is probably the most well-known page describing implementation of Perlin noise - it has all you need, you just need to put a bit of effort into understanding it.

If you are in Java and want ready-to-use solution, you could also use the noise generator implemented in [Java3D](http://code.j3d.org/javadoc/org/j3d/texture/procedural/PerlinNoiseGenerator.html). There are also many more Perlin noise implementations [floating around the web](http://hg.postspectacular.com/toxiclibs/src/b1955d9a378f/src.core/toxi/math/noise/PerlinNoise.java).

I personally prefer the [diamond-square algorithm](http://gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html) to the Perlin noise. It tends to generate less axially biased noise (that terrain features are suspiciously parallel to either of the main axes, creating visually distracting elements).

Comment: The links are all broken.